# Counting the ratio mysql

Tags: mysql, count

Say I have the following table,

I would like to select the ratio of all the names that start with `A` to all the names that start with `B`

For example

```
Name

ABC
DEF
VVV
BBB
BCD
ZZZ
```

So the output would be 0.5. I want to call that output 'out'.
So the output should be

```
out

0.5
```

pretty much what I want is

`Select count(*) from table where name like 'A%' / select count(*) from table where name like 'B%`'

but in a single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
select
   (select count(*) from table where name like 'a%') / (select count(*) from table where name like 'b%');
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/883c6/1).

Note that if the divisor is zero, mySql will coalesce the zero into a null and the resulting value will be `null`.  This is different than say, Oracle, which will throw a *divisor is equal to zero* exception.

[Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/883c6/2) showing this behavior, which you should probably trap and handle appropriately.

Comment: +1 Works perfectly! @Ankur use this. JOIN is not that readable.

Comment: Yea, I think the self-join would boil down to the same thing.  I wouldn't over-think it.

Comment: What if the second count of 'B%' is 0?

Comment: @valexhome - mySql seems to coalesce a 0 into a null, and `x / null` is `null`.  I just tried it in the SQL Fiddle.  Oracle, however, will throw a "divisor is equal to zero" exception.  Interesting!

Comment: Tried on Postgres and MS SQL as well, both will throw *divide by zero* errors.  I guess mySql is weird :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will do what you need:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'A%') /
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'B%')) AS `out`
```